# How to I unlock the 3rd item slot for a player in PES 2013?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2013

I am coming to the end of my first season in 'become a legend' mode and several seasons into 'master league'mode and I have noticed all the players have a 3rd locked item slot for additional skills and training boost items.

How can I unlock this for my 'become a legend' player and for all players in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a few different forum posts I found the only way to do this is to play Master League online until you unlock a bonus called '3rd Pocket' to use in Become A Legend or Master League offline mode.

The amount of matches this takes seems to vary a lot meaning it probably is a random reward.

Answer (score -6):

There is a tool called PESYOU.COM_PES2013 ITEM EDITOR which unlocks the 3rd pocket. Google it and follow the instructions.

Comment: Please don't include "google it" as an answer. Include the relevant information and link about the tool in your answer.